# vue3: odd case where displaying the full object is fine, yet accessing one of its elements returns undefined

Tags: vuejs3, dynamic-routing

I am building a forum, and passing the thread id dynamically via router-link as a prop. At the same time I am getting all the threads on the mounted hook, and then using a computed property to find the thread that corresponds to the id prop.

If on the template I inject the whole thread, it works perfectly. But, if I try to access one single element of it, I get an error saying that it can't get that element from undefined.

Could this be something to do with different timings between receiving the props and the mounted hook in relation to the creation phase and the execution phase? In any case, what is the correct way to get around this?

So with {{ thread.title }} I get: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')

Yet this works fine:

```
<div class="single-thread-card">
  <h1>{{ thread }}</h1>
</div>
```

Then the script:

```
  props: {
    id: {
      required: true,
      type: String
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/threads')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => this.threads = data)
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  },
  data( ) {
    return {
      threads: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    thread () {
      return this.threads.find(t => t.id === this.id)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `threads` is initially an empty array. Which means that `this.threads.find` will return `undefined`. This is true until the `fetch` call is finished. So simply "guard" any template elements using `thread` with `v-if="thread"` (rendering `{{ thread }}` is no problem because Vue sees it is undefined and simply renders nothing)

Comment: You nailed it Michael Levy! The v-if does the trick! Thank you :-)))